# Highcharts - programmatically slice

Tags: highcharts

I have following situation

http://prntscr.com/4ev01g

Pie from left has items that are categorized. Items from same category has same color.
Right column displays categories.

When use clicks on one of categories on right bar (i.e. orange) it should select/slice (explode) all orange slices.

UPDATE:

I have array of objects like this

```
[
  {name: 'Liontrust Special Situations Inst', category: 'Cat 1', value: 123.45},
  {name: 'Other item', category: 'Cat 1', value: 123.45},
  {name: 'More items', category: 'Cat 2', value: 123.45},
  {name: 'MOre items', category: 'Cat 3', value: 123.45},
]
```

So Pie represents "name-value" and column represents same array grouped by category and values are sum of value property for items in same category.

Comment: How exactly is this made? Two separate charts with similar options?

Comment: I updated it to answer you question. Thanks.

Comment: At the beginning please replicate your demo as live, on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Just find corresponding point in pie chart series, then call: `point.slice(true/false)`. Don't forget de-slice previously sliced points. [Docs reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.slice).

To detect click event on a right side (if it's Highcharts chart), then use [`series.point.events.click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) handler.